# Integration including the floor function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm aware of the way to quantify the following integral in the following way, however I'm trying to find another way to express the given integral. Especially when the function $f(x)$ is not particularly nice: $$F(x)=\int_0^x \lfloor{t}\rfloor f(t)dt=\sum_{k=1}^{x-1}\int_k^{k+1}kf(t)dt$$

Does anyone know of another way to solve this? (I'm fairly certain that the sum of the right is correct, if not can someone let me know)

Comment: Well you could use integration by parts to write the right-hand side as an expression involving $\int ktf'(t)\,dt$... or substitute $t=s^2$, or perhaps $t=1/s$, or all sorts of things.  But I kind of suspect this is not going to be helpful.  To get "another way" that is useful to you, I think you will need to give some details about what sorts of "other ways" might be of interest.

Comment: It would help if you give a specific example of a function that is challenging, or at least the nature about why it is challenging, as your simplification changes the problem from integrating $0$ to $x$, to integrating $k$ to $k+1$, which I would expect to be equally challenging for most general functions.

Comment: Thanks @David I did try this say that $u=f(t)\Rightarrow u'=f'(t)$ and $v'=\lfloor t\rfloor \Rightarrow v=\frac{1}{2} t(t-1)$ so the integral becomes $[\frac{1}{2}t(t-1)f(t)]_0^x-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^xt(t-1)f'(t)dt$. But this for some reason only gives a close approximation but I don't understand why